# Unable to change background color of treeview in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to change the background color of the rows in treeview using tags but unable to get the success. Following is my code:

```
def display_device_status(self, colnames):
    # root = Tk()
    # self.root.title('Device Status')
    # self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    # tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, height=25, column=("col1", "col2"), show="headings", selectmode="browse")
    # tree.heading('#1', text='MAC')
    # tree.column('#1',width=290)
    # tree.heading('#2', text='Status')
    # tree.column('#2',width=290)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, height=25, column=colnames, show="headings", selectmode="browse")
    # tree.option_add()
    for eachcol in colnames:
        tree.heading(column=eachcol, text=eachcol)
        tree.column(column=eachcol, width=290, minwidth=0)
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.root, orient="vertical")
    vsb.configure(command=tree.yview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    tree.pack(side="left")
    vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    # viewing_records(tree)
    records = tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        tree.delete(element)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Gateway_Log.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query_result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Status")
    for row in query_result:
        if row[1] == 1:
            tree.insert("", 'end', values=(row[0], 'Online'), tags = ('123',))
        else:
            tree.insert("", 'end', values=(row[0], 'Offline'), tags=('456',))
    tree.tag_configure('123', background='orange')
    tree.tag_configure('456', background='purple')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

when I run this code every time I am able to see background color as while only.

Please help me to change the background color of row.

Comment: If treeview is anything like the scrollbar or window borders you wont be able to change the color if you are on windows.

Comment: So what is best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the color of the rows the right way, but there is currently a bug with treeviews in Tcl: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=509cafafae so the row color set from the tag is overridden by the treeview background color set by the style.

While waiting for the fixed version of tcl/tk, you can use the fix suggested in the bug ticket:

```
style = ttk.Style()

def fixed_map(option):
    # Returns the style map for 'option' with any styles starting with
    # ("!disabled", "!selected", ...) filtered out

    # style.map() returns an empty list for missing options, so this should
    # be future-safe
    return [elm for elm in style.map("Treeview", query_opt=option)
            if elm[:2] != ("!disabled", "!selected")]

style.map("Treeview",
          foreground=fixed_map("foreground"),
          background=fixed_map("background"))
```