# TKinter Style & Treeview Click Issues

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, themes, tkinter.style

I am struggling with styles in TKinter
My main problem is that you cannot click anything in the treeview.

To test, simply press the "Press To Test" Button

For some reason it looks like, style.theme_create takes over my treeview widget, and no matter what I try, I cannot seem to find a solution around it. I tried activating the cursor, selection_set, focus_set, etc.

If I comment the style I can click, but not with it on.

I am still quite new to python and would appreciate some insight.

I tried the t1.bind('') and tried to find a selected style but can't seem to make it work, the bind on its own doesn't work. I've read the documentation but all i've tried related to the selection seems to fail.

```
#IMPORT LIBRARIES & MODULES
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk,Frame
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
from datetime import datetime,date,time
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import pyodbc
import os, sys
import ldap

#APPLICATION - Start of Application
newroot = Tk()

#APPLICATION - Configure New Window Parameters
newroot.geometry("1200x600")
newroot.title(' PCT ')
newroot.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
newroot.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#SET CUSTOM APPLICATION COLORS
bglight = '#7d8ea3'
bgmid = '#5a6b7e'
bgdark = '#3d4855'
cwhite = '#ffffff'
cgrey = '#dddddd'

#SET STYLING FOR MENU
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create( "fclassic", parent="alt", settings={
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {
                   "tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0],
                   "background": bgdark,
                   "foreground": cwhite}},

        "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], 
                   "background": bglight,
                   "foreground": cwhite,
                         "font": ("Century Gothic", '14', 'italic')},

                  "map": 
              {"background": [("selected", bgmid)],
                       "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]}}})
style.theme_use("fclassic")

#SET STYLING FOR TABLES
tvstyle = ttk.Style()
tvstyle.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=1, bd=0, background=cwhite, font=("Century Gothic", 10))
tvstyle.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", background=bglight, foreground=cwhite, font=("Century Gothic", 10, 'bold'))

#APPLICATION - Start Of Application Code
def PGT(): 

    def searchconfig():

        crecords = [('test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test'),('test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test'),('test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test')]
        rowalt = 0

        #SET TABLE ROW COLOR TAGS
        t1.tag_configure('evenrow', background=cgrey)
        t1.tag_configure('oddrow', background=cwhite)   

        #CLEAR TABLE
        for row in t1.get_children():
            t1.delete(row)

        #TABLE ENTRY LOOP                
        for record in crecords:

            #SET ROW COUNT
            rowalt = rowalt + 1

            #INSERT INTO TABLE WITH SPECIFIC TAGS DEPENDING OF STATEMENT
            if (rowalt % 2) == 0:
                t1.insert('', 'end', values=[record[0],record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4],record[5],record[6],record[7],record[8]],tags = ('evenrow'))
            else:
                t1.insert('', 'end', values=[record[0],record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4],record[5],record[6],record[7],record[8]],tags = ('oddrow'))

    def configtype():
        pass

    def searchserial():
        pass    

    #APPLICATION - START - Menu Setup
    ttk.Style().configure('TButton', background=bgdark)

    menu = ttk.Notebook()
    menu.pack(expan = 1, fill = "both")

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(menu, style='TButton')
    menu.add(tab1, text = "Main")

    tab2 = ttk.Frame(menu, style='TButton')
    menu.add(tab2, text = "About")
    #APPLICATION -  END  - Menu Setup

    #APPLICATION - START - Tab1 Design & Setup
    emptext1 = StringVar()
    sele_l1 = Label(tab1, text="Configuration", font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bgdark, fg = cwhite)
    sele_l1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    sele_e1 = Entry(tab1, width=15, textvariable=emptext1, justify='center', font=("Century Gothic", 14))
    sele_e1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    emptext1.set("TEST")

    tottext1 = StringVar()
    tote_l1 = Label(tab1, text="Numero De Serie", font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bgdark, fg = cwhite)
    tote_l1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
    tote_e1 = Entry(tab1, width=10, textvariable=tottext1, justify='center', font=("Century Gothic", 14))
    tote_e1.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)      


    emptext2 = StringVar()
    sele_l2 = Label(tab1, text="From", font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bgdark, fg = cwhite)
    sele_l2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    sele_e2 = Entry(tab1, width=10, textvariable=emptext2, justify='center', font=("Century Gothic", 14))
    sele_e2.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    emptext3 = StringVar()
    sele_l3 = Label(tab1, text="To", font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bgdark, fg = cwhite)
    sele_l3.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    sele_e3 = Entry(tab1, width=10, textvariable=emptext3, justify='center', font=("Century Gothic", 14))
    sele_e3.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    emptext4 = StringVar()
    sele_l3 = Label(tab1, text="Suprime RecID", font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bgdark, fg = cwhite)
    sele_l3.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    sele_e3 = Entry(tab1, width=10, textvariable=emptext4, justify='center', font=("Century Gothic", 14))
    sele_e3.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    runq_b1 = Button(tab1, text="Press To Test", command=searchconfig, font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bglight, fg = cwhite)
    runq_b1.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)

    runq_b2 = Button(tab1, text="Rechercher", command=searchserial, font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bglight, fg = cwhite)
    runq_b2.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)

    runq_b3 = Button(tab1, text="Modifier", command=searchserial, font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bglight, fg = cwhite)
    runq_b3.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)

    runq_b4 = Button(tab1, text="Transferer", command=searchserial, font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bglight, fg = cwhite)
    runq_b4.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, rowspan=2, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)

    runq_b5 = Button(tab1, text="Supprimer", command=searchserial, font=("Century Gothic", 14), bg = bglight, fg = cwhite)
    runq_b5.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)

    tf1 = Frame(tab1)
    tf1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, columnspan=8)
    t1 = ttk.Treeview(tf1, columns=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), show="headings", height="14", selectmode='browse', style="mystyle.Treeview") 
    t1.pack()

    t1.focus_set()

    t1.heading(1, text="RecID")
    t1.column(1 ,minwidth=60,width=70, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(2, text="Config Name")
    t1.column(2 ,minwidth=100,width=125, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(3, text="Config Type")
    t1.column(3 ,minwidth=100,width=120, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(4, text="Serial #")
    t1.column(4 ,minwidth=100,width=110, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(5, text="MAC Address")
    t1.column(5 ,minwidth=100,width=120, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(6, text="Company")
    t1.column(6 ,minwidth=100,width=180, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(7, text="Actif")
    t1.column(7 ,minwidth=60,width=60, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(8, text="All T.")
    t1.column(8 ,minwidth=60,width=80, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(9, text="Open T.")
    t1.column(9 ,minwidth=60,width=80, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(10, text="Project T.")
    t1.column(10 ,minwidth=60,width=80, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    t1.heading(11, text="Placeholder 2")
    t1.column(11 ,minwidth=100,width=130, stretch=NO, anchor="center")
    #APPLICATION -  END  - Tab1 Design & Setup

runapp = PGT()

newroot.mainloop()
```

This is a abreviated section of my entire app but still functional.

Comment: ***" cannot click anything"***: Click is working, you can verify by `t1.bind('<Button-1>', ...`You are loosing the `'selected'` style. Can't explain this, try to set a `'selected'` style for `Treeview` explicit.

Comment: "cannot click anything in the treeview"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: cannot click anything in the treeview.
>   Using `.theme_create` disables `selected` style in `Treeview`.

---

Click is working, you can verify this by binding a callback to the event `'<Button...`.

```
    def on_selected(event):
        print('on_selected{}'.format(event))

    t1.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', on_selected)
```

**Reference**:

- [`widget.bind(event, handler)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

  > For each widget, you can bind Python functions and methods to events.
  >   If an event matching the event description occurs in the widget, the given handler is called with an object describing the event.

---

You are loosing the `'selected'` style or the `'!selected'` style becomes the same. Therefore **no** color change happens if you click at a Row.

**Solution**:
Set **explicit** a `'selected'` style for the `Treeview` widget in your new `theme`.

```
style.theme_create("fclassic", parent="alt",
                   settings={
                        'Treeview': {
                            'map': {
                                'background': [('!selected', 'blue'), ('selected', 'red')],
                                'foreground': [('selected', 'black')],
                                'font': [('selected', ("Century Gothic", 10, 'bold'))],
                            }  # end 'map'
                        }  # end 'Treeview'
                   }  # end settings
                   )
```

**Reference**:

- [Changing Widget Colors](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors)

  > collect all the information on setting the colors of modern widgets

---

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: Thank you so very much, i've racked my brain on this for quite some time. The explanation was extremely helpful.